# Kivy reload Buttons(via function)on app startup

Tags: python, kivy, startup

Hi i'm pretty new with python and kivy , im trying to do a simple "to do" app.. My code looks horrible, i know, and im sorry for that..
I have a table in sqlite3 with some information stored in it. I would like to call a function that query this table on app start up. I can't figure out how to make it work.. Here is my code

Python:

```
import sqlite3
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from functools import partial


class GetLinksButton(Button):


    def get_caption(self):
#       DEFINIZIONE CHE SI POTREBBE FARE IN KV .. CREAZIONE POPUP CON 2 BOTTONI E TEXTINPUT
        content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        txt = TextInput(text = "",focus=False,multiline=False,size_hint=(1,0.2),font_size= 40)
        content.add_widget(txt)
        mybutton = Button(text='Add',size_hint=(1,0.2),font_size=20)
        mybutton2 = Button(text='Close',size_hint=(1,0.2),font_size=20)
        content.add_widget(mybutton)
        content.add_widget(mybutton2)

        mypopup = Popup(title = 'Add item to list',
            content = content,
            size_hint = (1, 0.4),
            auto_dismiss = False,
            ).open()

        def saveTxt(tt):
            mypopup.dismiss()   # FUNZIONE CHIAMATA, CHIUSURA POPUP
            try:
                self.set_caption(txt.text)  # CHIAMA FUNZIONE DI CREAZIONE BOTTONE CON ARG IL CAPTURE DEL TESTO IN TEXTBOX
            except:
                pass

        mybutton.bind(on_press = saveTxt)  # CHIAMA FUNZIONE DI CAPTURE DEL TESTO E CHIUSURA POPUP
        txt.bind(on_text_validate = saveTxt)# CHIAMA FUNZIONE DI CAPTURE DEL TESTO E CHIUSURA POPUP
        mybutton2.bind(on_press = mypopup.dismiss)


#   FUNZIONE CHIAMATA PER INSERIMENTO NUOVO BOTTONE IN TABELLA LOCALTB
    def btn_db(self,st):
        #con = None
        elementList =[]
        print "stringa dentro a dtn_db "+ st

        try:
            con = sqlite3.connect('localdb.db')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("insert into localtb (Item, State) values ( ?, ?)",(st, 0))
            con.commit()
            cur.execute("select * from localtb")
            data = cur.fetchall()
            con.close()
            for x in data:
                print x
                elementList.append(x[0])
        except:
            print "non va"
        w = str(elementList)
        return w


#   CREAZIONE BOTTONE DA INPUTO DI TESTO , TEXT BUTTON == INPUT INSERITO IN BOX
    def set_caption(self,stringa):
        string = stringa[0].upper()+stringa[1:].lower()
        print string, " stringa prima del for"
        # DA SISTEMARE CICLO "INUTILE"
        #for i in range(1):
        link_button = LinkButton(
            text = string)
        print "tra for e add_widget"
        self.links_grid.add_widget(link_button)
        print string," strinda PRIMA call a btn_db"
        self.btn_db(string)          # CALL A FUNZIONE PER INSERIRE IL BOTTONE IN TABELLA LOCALE (LOCALTB)
        print string," strinda DOPO call a btn_db"


class LinkButton(ToggleButton):

#   GESTIONE DEL TOGGLE.. QUNANDO SI TOGGLA IL BOTTONE PARTE LA QUERY E INVERTE LO STATO ATTUALE CON L'ALTRO STATO , DA 0 A 1 E VICEVERSA PER IL BOTTONE PREMUTO
    def toggleState(self):
        #con = None
        red = (83,0,0,1)
        green = (0,83,0,1)
        print self.background_color
        if self.background_color == [83,0,0,1]:
            self.background_color = green
        else:
            print "dentro ELSE"
            self.background_color = red
        elementList =[]
        pressed = str(self.text)
        print "tasto premuto cambio stato: "+pressed
        try:
            con = sqlite3.connect('localdb.db')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("update localtb set State = (CASE WHEN State = 0 THEN State + 1 WHEN State = 1 THEN State - 1 end ) WHERE Item = ?",(pressed,))  # ATTENTO ALLA VIRGOLA DOPO PRESSED(SE NON NON FUNZIONA)
            con.commit()
            cur.execute("select * from localtb")
            data = cur.fetchall()
            con.close()
            for x in data:
                print x
                elementList.append(x[0])
        except:
            print "non va"
        w = str(elementList)
        return w



class SmsButton(Button):

#   PROVE DI RELOAD SESSIONE PRECENDETE- FALLITE.
    def reloadSession(self):
        try:
            con = sqlite3.connect('localdb.db')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("select * from localtb")
            data = cur.fetchall()
            con.close()
            for x in data:
                reload_Element = str(x[0])
                if x[1] == 0:
                    print "in if: ", x[1]
                    link_button = LinkButton(text = reload_Element,background_color = [83,0,0,1])
                else:
                    print "in else: ", x[1]
                    link_button = LinkButton(text = reload_Element,background_color = [0,83,0,1])
                self.links_grid.add_widget(link_button)
        except Exception as inst:
            print inst.args
            print "non va"


class Test(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

KV:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

MyRootasdasd: 
    rows: 1
    RightArea:


<MyRootasdasd@GridLayout>: 
    #rows: 1
    #RightArea:



<RightArea@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    size_hint_x: 0.3
    spacing: '1dp'

    ScrollView:
        LinksGrid:
            id: links_grid

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: (1,0.08)


        GetLinksButton:
            links_grid: links_grid

        SmsButton:
            links_grid: links_grid


<LinksGrid@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    spacing: '.5dp'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

<SmsButton>:
    size_hint_y: 1 
    text: 'SMS'
    on_press: self.reloadSession()


<GetLinksButton>:

    size_hint_y: 1
    text: 'Get links'
    on_press: self.get_caption()    

<LinkButton>:
    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)   #COLORE TESTO
    background_normal: '' # RESET DELLA TINTA (STRINGA, quindi carica un immagine non un colore)
    background_color: (83, 0, 0, 1) #COLORE SFONDO -> qui sotto la call alla classe che gestisce il toggle del bottone
    on_release: self.toggleState()
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '80dp'
```

some pieces of code are unused don't worry about it.
Function i need to call is reloadSession that query table and then with the information retrieved create n buttons...
As you can see, in the SmsButton class(in KV) call that function(ON_PRESS), i need to do the same thing but automatically on app start up... How can i do that??

Sorry for my bad english and coding.. Im new, im trying a lot of stuff, i would appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Yvan.

EDIT: removed unused code

EDIT : @bj0
thanks for the tips.. i've tryied to use build function in alla the way i know. but it doesnt work ...i get this error
("'Test' object has no attribute 'links_grid'",)
the code im using now is this..

```
class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        try:
            con = sqlite3.connect('localdb.db')
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("select * from localtb")
            data = cur.fetchall()
            con.close()
            for x in data:
                reload_Element = str(x[0])
                if x[1] == 0:
                    print "in if: ", x[1]
                    link_button = LinkButton(text = reload_Element,background_color = [83,0,0,1])
                else:
                    print "in else: ", x[1]
                    link_button = LinkButton(text = reload_Element,background_color = [0,83,0,1])
                self.links_grid.add_widget(link_button)
        except Exception as inst:
            print inst.args
            print "non va"
```

obviously Test class has no links_grid attribute.. but how can i solve this problem ?
Thanks again

Comment: **"some pieces of code are unused don't worry about it."** Please remove that code so that those who can help you can better focus on your problem.

Comment: Check out: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build.  This function is called when Kivy first builds your application and I generally put startup code there.  Don't forget to do slow DB stuff *off* the GUI thread.

Comment: still have some problem.. check edit for more info..Thanks :)